# How to write a Feature state to a registry key

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

What is the best way to write, to a reg key, if a feature was installed during setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Component with condition speified. Condition may reference feature states (current or requested - for more details see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28VS.85%29.aspx)). I use '&' symbol - it gets requested (which should be achieved with installation) feature state.

```
<Component Id="MyComponentSpecificReg" Guid="YOURGUID">
    <Condition>&MyFeatureId = 3</Condition> <!--install this component only of feature requested state is LOCAL (You may need other condition - please read the link I posted above)-->
    <RegistryKey Root="YOUR REG ROOT" Key="YOUR REGISTRY PATH" Action="create">
        <RegistryValue Name="YourKeyName" Type="string" Value="[YOUR_PROPERTY]"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```